# Set up Varnish + Drupal on Docker

Tags: docker, drupal, docker-compose, varnish, varnish-vcl

I have three docker containers, one is running php5+apache with Drupal installed, and the other one is running varnish 4.1, and the last one is running MySQL. Here's my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    container_name: drupal.app
    build: .build/php5-apache
    working_dir: "/var/www/html/"
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ".:/var/www/html/"
    restart: always
    networks:
      vpcbr:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.5
    links:
      - db
  db:
    container_name: drupal.db
    #image: mysql:5.5
    build: .build/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dskjfskjhfnksdnf
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      vpcbr:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.4
    restart: always
  varnish:
    container_name: drupal.varnish
    build: .build/varnish
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      vpcbr:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.3
    restart: always
    tty: true
networks:
  vpcbr:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
     config:
       - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
         gateway: 10.5.0.1
```

And here's the default.vcl for the varnish

```
#
# This is an example VCL file for Varnish.
#
# It does not do anything by default, delegating control to the
# builtin VCL. The builtin VCL is called when there is no explicit
# return statement.
#
# See the VCL chapters in the Users Guide at https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/
# and https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExamples for more examples.

# Marker to tell the VCL compiler that this VCL has been adapted to the
# new 4.0 format.
vcl 4.0;

# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
    .host = "10.5.0.5";
    .port = "80";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    # Happens before we check if we have this in cache already.
    #
    # Typically you clean up the request here, removing cookies you don't need,
    # rewriting the request, etc.

  set req.backend_hint = bar.backend();

  # Do not cache these paths.
  if (req.url ~ "^/status\.php$" ||
      req.url ~ "^/update\.php" ||
      req.url ~ "^/install\.php" ||
      req.url ~ "^/apc\.php$" ||
      req.url ~ "^/admin" ||
      req.url ~ "^/admin/.*$" ||
      req.url ~ "^/user" ||
      req.url ~ "^/user/.*$" ||
      req.url ~ "^/users/.*$" ||
      req.url ~ "^/info/.*$" ||
      req.url ~ "^/flag/.*$" ||
      req.url ~ "^.*/ajax/.*$" ||
      req.url ~ "^.*/ahah/.*$" ||
      req.url ~ "^/system/files/.*$") {

    return (pass);
  }

  # Always cache the following file types for all users. This list of extensions
  # appears twice, once here and again in vcl_backend_response so make sure you edit both
  # and keep them equal.
  if (req.url ~ "(?i)\.(pdf|asc|dat|txt|doc|xls|ppt|tgz|csv|png|gif|jpeg|jpg|ico|swf|css|js)(\?.*)?$") {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
  }

  # Remove all cookies that Drupal doesn't need to know about. We explicitly
  # list the ones that Drupal does need, the SESS and NO_CACHE. If, after
  # running this code we find that either of these two cookies remains, we
  # will pass as the page cannot be cached.
  if (req.http.Cookie) {
    # 1. Append a semi-colon to the front of the cookie string.
    # 2. Remove all spaces that appear after semi-colons.
    # 3. Match the cookies we want to keep, adding the space we removed
    #    previously back. (\1) is first matching group in the regsuball.
    # 4. Remove all other cookies, identifying them by the fact that they have
    #    no space after the preceding semi-colon.
    # 5. Remove all spaces and semi-colons from the beginning and end of the
    #    cookie string.
    set req.http.Cookie = ";" + req.http.Cookie;
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "; +", ";");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";(SESS[a-z0-9]+|SSESS[a-z0-9]+|NO_CACHE)=", "; \1=");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";[^ ][^;]*", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "^[; ]+|[; ]+$", "");

    if (req.http.Cookie == "") {
      # If there are no remaining cookies, remove the cookie header. If there
      # aren't any cookie headers, Varnish's default behavior will be to cache
      # the page.
      unset req.http.Cookie;
    }
    else {
      # If there is any cookies left (a session or NO_CACHE cookie), do not
      # cache the page. Pass it on to Apache directly.
      return (pass);
    }
  }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Happens after we have read the response headers from the backend.
    #
    # Here you clean the response headers, removing silly Set-Cookie headers
    # and other mistakes your backend does.
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Happens when we have all the pieces we need, and are about to send the
    # response to the client.
    #
    # You can do accounting or modifying the final object here.
}
```

I have used curl to test if the varnish server can connect to the drupal server through the ip 10.5.0.5 and the result is positive.

However, whenever I try to access the web through http://localhost/ the varnish always gives me 503 error and can't fetch the Backend.

Can anyone tell me is there something wrong with my default.vcl setting or the docker-compose setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am not sure if the bridge works this way, have you tried using just the "name" `varnish`  in the default vcl instead of the ip-address?

Answer (score 1):

Where did you try to access the URL `http://localhost` from?

From what I know, Varnish cache should be placed in another instance and not the same instance which you are trying to cache the content. So, you should be pointing the URL to the Varnish cache which is not supposed to be `10.5.0.5`.

Your Vanish VCL settings seems to be correct which is listening to caching the content from `10.5.0.5` at port `80` though.